# Raku and cupsGetDests

Tags: raku

Fedora 33

I am trying to output a list of printers from cupsGetDests2 using Raku.

This is the C way, although it shows deleted printers as well:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cups/cups.h> 

int main() { 
cups_dest_t* dests; 
int nCount = cupsGetDests2(CUPS_HTTP_DEFAULT, &dests); 

for (int i = 0; i < nCount; i++) { 
   cups_dest_t dest = dests[i]; 
   std::cout << dest.name << std::endl; 
   } 
} 


$ list-printers 
B4350 
Cups-PDF 
Cups_PDF_rn6                <-- deleted 
Oki_B4350_on_dev_lp0_rn6    <-- deleted 
Virtual_PDF_Printer 
Virtual_PDF_Printer_rn6     <-- deleted
```

I added the ”<-- deleted” remarks, but that is a story for another day.

A friend over on the Raku mailing list, showed me this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku 

use NativeCall; 
class CupsDest is repr('CStruct') { 
   has Str $.name;      # This is the first field in the struct -- add more if you need them 
} 

sub cupsGetDests(Pointer is rw --> int32) is native('cups') {} 

my $ptr = Pointer.new; 
my $nCount = cupsGetDests($ptr); 

for ^$nCount -> $i { 
    my $dest = nativecast(CupsDest, Pointer.new($ptr + $i * 
nativesizeof(Pointer))); 
    say $dest.name; 
}
```

But it errors out with this output:

```
$ ListPrinters.pl6 
Cannot locate native library 'libcups.so': libcups.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory 
 in method setup at /opt/rakudo-pkg/share/perl6/core/sources/947BDAB9F96E0E5FCCB383124F923A6BF6F8D76B (NativeCall) line 298 
 in block cupsGetDests at /opt/rakudo-pkg/share/perl6/core/sources/947BDAB9F96E0E5FCCB383124F923A6BF6F8D76B (NativeCall) line 587
```

And libcups is really there!

```
$ locate libcups.so 
/usr/lib/libcups.so.2 
/usr/lib64/libcups.so.2
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Many thanks,

New info:

I did the following:

```
# cd /usr/lib
# ln -s libcups.so.2 libcups.so
# ls -al libcups*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  14612 Nov 10 06:07 libcupsimage.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     12 Dec  6 01:03 libcups.so -> libcups.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 710236 Nov 10 06:07 libcups.so.2

# cd /usr/lib64
# ln -s libcups.so.2 libcups.so
# ls -al libcups*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     23 Nov 23 22:09 libcupsfilters.so.1 -> libcupsfilters.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 264440 Nov 23 22:09 libcupsfilters.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  15256 Nov 10 06:08 libcupsimage.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     12 Dec  6 01:04 libcups.so -> libcups.so.2
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 686128 Nov 10 06:08 libcups.so.2
```

Running the program now gives:

```
$ ListPrinters.pl6 
B4350
(Str)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is my list of printers:

```
$ lpstat -a
B4350 accepting requests since Thu 29 Oct 2020 01:36:30 PM PDT
Cups-PDF accepting requests since Tue 30 Apr 2019 04:05:39 PM PDT
Virtual_PDF_Printer accepting requests since Tue 29 Sep 2020 03:13:17 AM PDT
```

Now what am I doing wrong?

Solved with Curt's help.  My new code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku

use NativeCall;

class CupsDest is repr('CStruct') {
    has Str $.name;
    has Str $.instance;
    has int32 $.is-default;
    has int32 $.num-options;
    has Pointer $.options;
}

sub cupsGetDests(Pointer is rw --> int32) is native('cups', v2) {}

my $ptr = Pointer.new;
my $nCount = cupsGetDests($ptr);

for ^$nCount -> $i {
    my $dest = nativecast(CupsDest, Pointer.new($ptr + $i * nativesizeof(CupsDest)));
    print "<" ~ $dest.name ~ ">\n";
}
```

Output:

```
$ ListPrinters.pl6
<B4350>
<Cups-PDF>
<Cups_PDF_rn6>
<Oki_B4350_on_dev_lp0_rn6>
<Virtual_PDF_Printer>
```

Comment: It's not finding the library by the precise name it's indicating. You'll have to symlink one of those versions to libcups.so in a suitable (and findable) directory.

Comment: *"Cannot locate native library 'libcups.so'"* This did not happen for me. I tried this on Ubuntu 20.04, with the library provided by package `libcups2-dev` and installed at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcups.so`, and it finds the library here.

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, you should accept it.

Answer (score 4):

You've already got the symlink to the plain `.so`, but you can also just change `is native('cups')` to `is native('cups', v2)` to make it use the `.so.2` library.

@jjmerelo has the right answer -- I was thinking it was an array of pointers, but it is actually an array of structs.

Fill in the whole Struct:

```
class CupsDest is repr('CStruct') {
    has Str $.name;
    has Str $.instance;
    has int32 $.is-default;
    has int32 $.num-options;
    has Pointer $.options;
}
```

and change this line:

```
my $dest = nativecast(CupsDest, Pointer.new($ptr + $i * nativesizeof(CupsDest)));
```

Comment: Hi Curt,  Works perfect.  Than you!   I will tack my new code on to the bottom of the original post.   I had no clue about the v2 thing.

Comment: Due to my carelessness I initially left out num-options -- just added it.

Comment: Thank you!   Not sure why you entered it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the definition of the function you're calling](https://www.cups.org/doc/cupspm.html#cupsGetDests2), couple of things pop out

- `dests` probably has a more complex structure that the one you're describing here. Besides [name](https://www.cups.org/doc/cupspm.html#cups_dest_s), it includes some other fields, like `instance`.
- You're using a number of bytes that corresponds to the size of a generic Pointer, not the size of the data structure that will hold that kind of struct. I would say it's got three pointers, plus a couple of ints. You'll probably need to use `nativesizeof(CupsDest)` once it's defined properly.

Comment: Any hints on how to do that?

Comment: I removed the sym links.    I deliberately want to use the v2 thing so I remember it next time